# How to get the text closest to the html element tag

Tags: javascript, jquery

I got this html snippet:

```
<label>
  <input type="checkbox"/>
  text here
</label>
```

in my js, i want to retrieve the 'text here' value

this is my js:

```
$('input[type=checkbox]').click(function (e) {
var msg = e.target.closest???
});
```

Comment: var msg = e.target.parentElement.textContent;

Answer (score 5):

You can use DOM node `nextSibling` property:

```
$('input[type=checkbox]').click(function (e) {
    var msg = this.nextSibling.nodeValue;
    console.log(msg);
});
```

```js
$('input[type=checkbox]').click(function (e) {
    var msg = this.nextSibling.nodeValue;
    alert(msg);    
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label>
    <input type="checkbox" />text here
</label>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [**contents()**](https://api.jquery.com/contents/)

```js
$('input[type=checkbox]').click(function(e) {
  var contents = $(this).closest('label').contents();
  var msg = contents[2];
  console.log(msg);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label>
  <input type="checkbox" />text here
</label>
```

Or in your simple case, [**text()**](https://api.jquery.com/text/) and [**trim()**](https://api.jquery.com/trim/)

```js
$('input[type=checkbox]').click(function(e) {
  var msg = $(this).closest('label').text().trim();
  console.log(msg);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label>
  <input type="checkbox" />text here
</label>
```

Answer (score 0):

[`parent()`](http://api.jquery.com/parent/) and [`text()`](http://api.jquery.com/text/) combined seem a good way to get that text.
Click run below and then click your label.

```js
$('input[type=checkbox]').click(function (e) {
var msg = $(this).parent().text()
$('#t').text(msg)
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label>
  <input type="checkbox"/>
  text here
</label>

<p id="t"></p>
```

About the `nextSibling` solutions, if your text is before the `<input>`, there will be nothing to return... Since you have just a `<label>` as parent, in this particular case, I'd personally recommend using the `<input>`'s `parent()` and then its `text()`, which will always return all the text inside the `<label>` and nothing else: a checkbox does not have text(s) associated.

Answer (score 0):

Try with `nextSibling` property of javascript.

Code snippets:

```
$('input[type=checkbox]').click(function (e) {
    var ele = $(this);
    var msg = ele[0].nextSibling.nodeValue;
    alert(msg);
    });
```

Hope this helps you!!!

Comment: No after posting my answer only I saw your answer which is similar to me. If any problem means I can remove my answer.

Comment: It's not my answer, but he did post exactly what you have... Well, maybe not exactly: he didn't use another var...

Comment: @Armfoot While am typing my answer, I could see "AmmarCSE" answer only. My page couldn't loaded properly I think.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.closest()` function of jQuery

```
$('input[type=checkbox]').click(function(e) {
  var msg = $(this).closest('label').text();
  alert(msg);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Following snippet will work for your HTML

```js
$('input[type=checkbox]').parent().text();
```